# Buttons for switching between text styles are not working in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Super noob question, I am just starting out with jQuery.

What I want to do is to have two buttons that change a heading's styling. When you click on the red button, the h1 becomes red; when you click on the yellow button, the h1 becomes yellow.

The buttons work, just once, and then... they stop working. What am I missing here?

Here's the code.

HTML

```
<h1>mywebsite</h1>
<button id="red">red</button>
<button id="yellow">yellow</button>
```

CSS

```
.red {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var title = $("h1");
   $("#red").click(function() {
     title.addClass("red")
   });

   $("#yellow").click(function() {
     title.addClass("yellow");
  });
 });
```

Comment: You need to remove the class as well probably. `addClass` will keep on adding a class. At the second click you'll have `<h1 class="red yellow">title<h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your class is being added but never being removed.

You can fix this by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var title = $("h1");
   $("#red").click(function() {
     title.addClass("red");
     title.removeClass("yellow");
   });

   $("#yellow").click(function() {
     title.addClass("yellow");
     title.removeClass("red");
  });
 });
```

Anyways, I would do this different and instead of playing with classes I would just dynamically add CSS style with `.css()` JQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var title = $("h1");
   $("#red").click(function() {
     title.css("color", "red");
   });

   $("#yellow").click(function() {
     title.css("color", "yellow");
  });
 });
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I'm dumb! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Short version

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#red, #yellow").click(function() {
      $("h1").removeClass().addClass(this.id);
   });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Its always a good idea to include an explanation of what your code is doing  in a verbal way along with your answer.  Answers with just code typically will be down-voted and possibly deleted, FYI.

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I like this! The more you know.